# making captcha image indetated in php

Tags: php

how can i make the captcha image produced by this script indent`enter code here`ed or italic or twisted like?

```
<?php
session_start();
$captchanumber = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$captchanumber = substr(str_shuffle($captchanumber), 0, 5);
$_SESSION["code"]=$captchanumber;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165); //background color blue
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color white
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5,5,5,  $captchanumber, $fg);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By loading in a custom font, you can skip all the "hard" parts by manipulating the font manually.

```
$font = imageloadfont('./myfont.gdf');
imagestring($im, $font, 5, 5, $captchanumber, $fg);
```

You can download custom fonts at various websites, such as;

- https://www.acidfonts.com
- http://www.dafont.com/

But make sure you check their licensing terms.